# ImportError: cannot import name 'ReLU'. in Keras 2.1.3

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Using Keras 2.1.3 I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'ReLU'` on `from keras.layers import ReLU`, what is the proper way to import `ReLU` in Keras 2.1.3?

I can import `ReLU` in Keras 2.2.2:

```
   import keras as k
   print(k.__version__)
   from keras.layers import ReLU
```

Yes, I know about `Activation('relu')`, but I'm looking for `ReLU` function used in [MobileNet implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py#L386)

**UPDATE:**

Looking at `mobilenet.py` of Keras 2.1.3, seems they use:

```
def relu6(x):
    return K.relu(x, max_value=6)
```

According to this thread https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7431 in Keras 2.1.3 custom layers of mobilenet can be imported like:

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import relu6
from keras.applications.mobilenet import DepthwiseConv2D
```

Comment: Isn't the normal way to just import `Activation` and pass `"relu"` to its constructor?

Comment: @erip it's not the same, I need `ReLU` with parameters like here https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py#L386

Comment: ReLU is defined in later keras versions (2.2.x), so you can maybe just update keras to get it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I can't update it because I need to convert it to coreml, which only work with Keras 2.1.3.

Comment: @mrgloom then use mobilenet from that keras version, not from the master branch of keras-applications

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro This is what I'm trying to do, but I need redefine some layers, so I just copy-paste MobileNet but it depends on some layers in 2.1.3 it is `relu6`
and `DepthwiseConv2D`.

Comment: @mrgloom No, you are doing it wrong, the keras.applications inside keras 2.1.3 works with keras 2.1.3. If you use the version from git master it will require a newer version of Keras.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `keras.layers.ReLU`, hence your inport error. Relu is an activation `keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0.0)`

The code you referenced defines layers as:

```
global backend, layers, models, keras_utils
backend, layers, models, keras_utils = get_submodules_from_kwargs(kwargs)
```

I'm not quite sure what this does (it's defined [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/61de21815728aa66377ebb2a7b4c2f5492a34dd2/keras_applications/__init__.py)).

I find this code confusing, because I often import layers using `from keras import layers`.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see where is `ReLU` defined.

Comment: This appears out of date compared to [the keras documentation on ReLU layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/relu/) - it is a `Layer` class.